# How to use existing credentials from other system in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

How to store username and hashed password retrieved from other system into Drupal. The point is one person having account in other system not need to register in Drupal application again, he should able to login with the same credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve this is to use LDAP in your network. This of course if the other system also has support for LDAP.

How to setup LDAP in your Drupal installation you can find here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/997082

How to configure LDAP for you network I have no clue about but guess you can just google it. Not much info but hope it will point you in right direction.